# Cannot convert from bool to FMResult set for SQL query results?

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I am utilizing FMDB as a way to integrate a SQLite database into my XCode project. I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/fmdb-sqlite-database/) on the matter and it has been excellent, for the most part. Creating a table and inserting objects into the table has been painless. However, I run into a bit of an issue when try to save queried results from db to a variable in app. Here is the code I use for this desired process (including the struct for the variable's type):

```
struct pulledMessage{
    var userIDs: String
    var userNames: String
    var message: String
    var sender: String
    var messageNumber: Int
}
func loadMessageData() -> [pulledMessage]!{
        var messagesPulled: [pulledMessage]!

        if openDatabase(){//correctly opens the database
            let query = "select * from messages order by messageNumber asc"
            do{
                print(database)
                let results: FMResultSet = try database.executeStatements(query)
                //^statement above causes error
                //The type FMResultSet is not usable for some reason
                while results.next(){
                    let message = pulledMessage(userIDs: String(results.string(forColumn: "userIDs")), userNames: String(results.string(forColumn: "userNames")), message: String(results.string(forColumn: "message")), sender: String(results.string(forColumn: "sender")), messageNumber: Int(results.string(forColumn: "messageNumber")))
                    if messagesPulled == nil{
                        messagesPulled = [pulledMessage]()
                    }
                    messagesPulled.append(contentsOf: message)
                }

            }
            catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            database.close()
        }
        return messagesPulled


    }
```

Now the issue that I am currently running into isn't necessarily logic-flow oriented. I can understand the process and what the commands are trying to do. The issue is rather with the line `let results = try database.executeStatements(query)`. This line is a near direct copy of the one found on the aforementioned database, though it is the cause of the error in the `results.next()` line and the `let messages = pulledMessage(...)`. The `.executeStatements` means that results has the type of `bool`. `.next()` cannot be called on type `bool` and I also cannot do `results.string` or whatever. While I understand the issue, I do not know how to amend it. Since `.executeStatements` will return a `bool`, and not the actual result of the `select * from messages` SQL command, how can I set `results` to whatever type/object that the tutorial seems to have intended?

Edit: I would like to set the results of the query as a `FMResultSet` so that I can use `.next()` and assign my variable to some of the result's properties. However, the method for which I have tried to do that (viewable in the code I have posted) is setting: `let results: FMResultSet = try database.executeStatments()`. This, though, gives me an error that I cannot convert a bool to an FMResultSet, so I am stuck?

Comment: you have to call let results:FMResultSet = try database.executeQuery(query, values: nil) instead of let results: FMResultSet = try database.executeStatments(), because executeQuery() returns FMResultSet while executeStatments() returns Bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func loadMessageData() -> [pulledMessage]!{
        var messagesPulled: [pulledMessage]!

        if openDatabase(){
            let query = "select * from messages order by messageNumber asc"
            do{
                print(database)
                let results:FMResultSet = try database.executeQuery(query, values: nil)

                while results.next(){
                    let message = pulledMessage(userIDs: String(results.string(forColumn: "userIDs")), userNames: String(results.string(forColumn: "userNames")), message: String(results.string(forColumn: "message")), sender: String(results.string(forColumn: "sender")), messageNumber: Int(results.string(forColumn: "messageNumber")))
                    if messagesPulled == nil{
                        messagesPulled = [pulledMessage]()
                    }
                    messagesPulled.append(contentsOf: message)
                }

            }
            catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            database.close()
        }
        return messagesPulled


    }
```

Try with this

Comment: Ignore my previous comment... The result of `try database.executeQuery()` is a bool and setting result as `:FMResultSet` returns an error that I cannot convert `bool` to `FMResultSet`

Comment: you have to call let results:FMResultSet = try database.executeQuery(query, values: nil) instead of let results: FMResultSet = try database.executeStatments(), because executeQuery() returns FMResultSet while executeStatments() returns Bool